# Save as syntax and range.select index syntax?

Tags: arrays, excel, save-as, vba

I'm trying to write some lines of codes that select a range in excel but the index to the range has a syntax error any suggestions? Also I'm trying to save a XML file as an xlsm file with file names from the concactenation of two file names stored in an array and is getting a similar error.any suggestions??

```
        Range (Allfiles(index)).select 'Allfiles is an array containing the file names ' type error


        Activeworkbooks.saveas "c:\Allfiles(1):&:Allfiles (count).xlsm", fileformat=52 'error
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get an "error", a useful "error message" will give you a hint as to what the problem is. By reading this message and acting upon it, you can debug your code step by step.

```
Activeworkbooks.SaveAs "c:\Allfiles(1):&:Allfiles (count).xlsm", FileFormat = 52
'                                           Variable not defined ^
```

The way to specify arguments in VBA is with `:=`, not `=`. Let's correct that and run it again...

```
Activeworkbooks.SaveAs "c:\Allfiles(1):&:Allfiles (count).xlsm", FileFormat:=52
' ^ Variable not defined
```

It's called `ActiveWorkbook`, not `Activeworkbooks`. Let's correct that and run it once more...

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\Allfiles(1):&:Allfiles (count).xlsm", FileFormat:=52
'                                     ^ The file could not be accessed.
```

I can't claim to know for sure what OS you're running, but given the `C:\`, I'll assume some flavour of Windows. You may know that `:` is an illegal character in paths in Windows?

Anyhow, I'm not sure where you're trying to save this file. My best guess:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\" & Allfiles(1) & Allfiles(UBound(Allfiles)) & ".xlsm", _
    FileFormat:=52
```

As for you first line of code, `Range (Allfiles(index)).Select`, I have no clue what you're trying to do there. You may want to read Excel-VBA's help file to learn what `Range` does.